# What is the Android equivalent of /dev/video0 for tablet Camera?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Is there any /dev/video0 file for Android Camera? I want to capture camera preview through ffmpeg on Android. Such as;

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 out.mpeg
```

Comment: did you find your ans? I am facing same issue. 
Cannot open video device /dev/video0: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Answer is probably very device-dependent and in most cases you will fail to use v4l camera directly without rooting/using custom rom on a device. Here's why:

- Device maker might provide closed-source, v4l-incompatible camera drivers (Android Compatibility Definition doesn't say anything about video4linux-compatible camera drivers) or,
- /dev/video* files might be inaccessible from application/shell because of file permissions (I see /dev/video20 device on my phone, but file is accessible only by root)

However, there is a nice Java API for camera access: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html